# Removing controller function name from URL in Codeigniter. Error when multiple controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, config

Using CI how can I route to specific contoller with any method name.
I have two controller : init and cms. Then in config.routes.php :

```
 $default_controller = "init";  //default controller
 $controller_exceptions = array('admin','forums');

 $route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
 $route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';
 $route['404_override'] = '';

 $route['backend'] = 'cms';
 $route['backend/(:any)'] = "cms/product";
```

When backend/product is typed I want it to route to backend/product. Again when backend/login is typed I want it to route to backend/login. That means what I need is `$route['backend/anyMethodNameAfterbackend'] = "cms/anyMethodNameAfterbackend";`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$route['backend/(:any)'] = "cms/product";` use `$route['cms/(:any)'] = "cms/$1";`
The result would be :

```
$route['backend'] = 'cms';
$route['backend/(:any)'] = "cms/$1";
```

Comment: Its not working. I did the same. Real path for login to my site is. `localhost/c2c/index.php/cms. This has login form with action `form_open('cms/login'). I typed localhost/c2c/backend then pages opens but when trying to login throws an 404 error.

Comment: Well then, try `form_open(base_url().'cms/login')` or `form_open('/cms/login')`.

Comment: Still not working. When trying to login. Press login then my url becomes `localhost/c2c/cms/login` not `localhost/c2c/backend/login`

Comment: That would be the same. You have another problem, one that is not related to routing. If you change `'/cms/login'`, to `'/backend/login'`, the uri will be correct, but the page will display the same error. What does your **cms** controller look like?

Comment: cms controller is simple that contains functions. I remember that i am removing the contoller name to be written in url by configuring htaccess. Does it make problem

Comment: You must display the script to be sure. But does cms controller contain the login function?

Comment: Yes sure. It does contain the login function. Ok i am editing with my htaccess file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72333/discussion-between-valentin-valentin-and-user254153).